# Is it efficient to archive-n-compress or compress-n-archive storage size-wise?

Tags: gzip, archive

I'm trying to archive old files (1000+) and thinking of two options

1. gzip individual files and then create a zip
2. create gzip using `tar cvzf`  on group of files

Not sure what would be most efficient in terms of storage of space.

Any info, that would help understanding what's best practice ?

Comment: I'd guess B) tar them up with compression.  Compression works (100,000 foot view) by finding duplicate bit strings and replacing them with a shorter pointer to a common bit string for uncompression. Therefore, compression is more efficient working on bigger blobs of data.

Comment: (and that^ can be best seen in the trivial case where you have 1000+ identical files)

Comment: tar-then-compress also compresses the padding and headers in the tar file, which can be significant if there are many small files.

Comment: also, if by "create a zip" you mean a '.zip' file (e.g. with zip or 7z, etc), then unless you need to transfer the archive to a machine that doesn't have tar and gzip as standard utils (like windows) and which you can't install tar and gzip on (not true for windows, there are several implementations for win), then don't use `zip` on unix or linux.     zip, unzip, 7z, etc are useful on unix/linux as compatibility tools but you're better off using native tools like tar or cpio or pax (for archiving) and gzip, bzip2, xz, etc (for compression).

Answer (score 0):

Using gzip and then zip is redundant.  Zip has its own compression, although it may or may not be as high as gzip.  Using zip is probably better if you want to extract individual files from the resulting archive.

Using tar to collect the files and then gzip will likely give you a higher compression ratio, as you can get compression between files as well as within files.  However, you have to uncompress them together to even get a listing of what is in the archive, as well as extract single files.   If you would always extract the entire archive, this is moot.

Note also, you can do this all as one step.  For example,

```
tar cf - somedir | gzip -9 > somedir.tar.gz
```

or equivalently

```
tar czf somedir.tar.gz somedir
```

Alternately, you could use xz (or J option instead of z) which gets an even higher compression ratio at the expense of significantly longer compression time.  (But if this is long term archiving, you may not care how long it takes to compress.)